# CSS not getting applied even though console shows no error

Tags: php, html, css

I am designing page in CI framework and have correctly included files but the css is not getting applied even though browser shows its calling them correctly..not sure where I am going wrong.

Below is the code I have written:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>login</title>
        <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>

    </head>
    <body class="bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card card-login mx-auto mt-5">
          <div class="card-header">Please enter your login details:</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="User name" name="name" type="text"  id="name" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
              </div>
              <div>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
      <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js');?>"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js');?>"></script>
      <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
      <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js');?>"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

When I click on browser by pressing F12 I get this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>login</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS-->
  <link href="http://localhost/polyropes_new/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="http://localhost/polyropes_new/assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Page level plugin CSS-->
  <link href="http://localhost/polyropes_new/assets/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css">
  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="http://localhost/polyropes_new/assets/css/sb-admin.css">

    </head>
    <body class="bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="card card-login mx-auto mt-5">
          <div class="card-header">Please enter your login details:</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Username</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="User name" name="name" type="text"  id="name" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
              </div>
              <div>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
      <script src="http://localhost/polyropes_new/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://localhost/polyropes_new/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
      <script src="http://localhost/polyropes_new/assets/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

This shows all files and CSS have been called correctly as none of them is blank.Please guide me

Comment: Ctrl + U Code And See What Path Is You get

Comment: Inspect the specific element where the CSS should have been applied and check if it's getting your styles or not

Comment: Its applying user agent stylesheet...how to remove this one ?

Comment: You can't. "user agent stylesheet" just means the default setting in the absense of any css files. so something must be going on the the css files.

Comment: Oh wait, you don't have `rel="stylesheet"` in the links. That's the problem.

Comment: Brilliant that solved the issue however the sidebar is coming on the top?

Comment: @JignaJain If you have an unrelated problem, can you post a new question please?